# Is it appropriate to ask about plotting/graphing/visualizing data here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I would like to ask for advice about plotting a growth curve model, preferably using SAS, SPSS or Excel. Is that an appropriate question for CrossValidated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the question is purely about how to make the plot in some software, but you know which plot you want to make, it is off-topic here, and better asked at https://stackoverflow.com/.

But if the question also is about how to choose a way of plotting, how to choose between different possibilities, then it is a statistical question and on-topic here. Often these two aspects got intermingled, then you have a choice, but if the programming aspect is secondary, it is on-topic here to (and maybe also at the other site).

Comment: In practice, I think some people kind of cheat, right? Add some statistics around the question when they actually want the code. What's the appropriate protocol when this happens? Answer, right?

Comment: @mribeirodantas The appropriate protocol is to flag off-topic but otherwise clear posts for migration to a suitable SE site (or to vote to migrate them, if you have that privilege).

Comment: Thanks, @whuber!